# Cannot import anything in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 15 Ultimate Edition and whenever I try to open an iml file created from a previous version of IntelliJ I get the message 'Cannot import anything from project'. How do I rectify this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to import just a bare iml file, or are there actual source files in the project as well?

Comment: Open the pom instead. If you don't have a pom then you're SOL.

Answer (score 7):

I think I have a solution - your Maven plugin must be disabled. (Mine had disabled itself for some reason).

So, go to Settings -> Plugins and enable "Maven 2 Integration" plugin (by ticking the checkbox). Click "Apply" and restart IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to import just .iml file I got the same error. Try to import the whole directory and check if you are importing the right files.